# Повторное выполнение метода qt

Tags: qtcreator, qt, c++

Пишу программу, которая вырисовывает определенное поле, а затем по клику мышки изменяются определенные данные, на основе которых происходит рисование объекта. Так вот, мне нужно, чтобы после выполнения mousepressevent программа возвращалась к уже выполненному paintevent , и выполняла его часть снова. Как бы мне это реализовать?

Comment: Выделите общую часть кода в отдельную процедуру, например.

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется вызвать перерисовку виджета немедленно, то для этого используется метод `QWidget::repaint()`, который в `QWidget` имеет несколько вариаций, дабы можно было указать не только прямоугольное выделение (`QRect`) для перерисовки, но и всяко-разно замысловатую геометрическую область (`QRegion`).

Однако в большинстве случаев лучше использовать `QWidget::update()`, который поставит вызов перерисовки виджета в очередь событий и при наличии в очереди нескольких одинаковых произведёт перерисовку виджета лишь один раз, сгруппировав события автоматически. Состав аргументов у метода `update()` тот же самый, что и у `repaint()`.

Если же параметры при перерисовки не касаются собственно координат области перерисовки, а должны иметь произвольный характер, то просто вносятся дополнительные флаги, которые внутри обработчика событий перерисовки будут формировать соответствующую логику выполнения.